# Extract urls from string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

I am working on a link preview script like fb uses it for example. The user creates a post that could potentially include links. On every keyup i test if the last key has been the space key and if that was the case i run my function:

```
function link_preview(event)
{
    var replyText = $("#answer_two").val();

    if(event.keyCode == 32)
    {
        var match = /^(?:[a-z]*?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/i.exec(replyText);

        if(match!="")
        {

            var preview = match[0];
        }
    }
}
```

So the user types a text that includes a link. When the link is detected a preview is shown with the information fetched from this url. The user has the option to close this preview and to add another link and this is exactly where my problems start. I can not access the second url and ignore the first. And all this gets even more complicated if a third url would be added to the mix.
Has anyone a suggestion on how to work this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding the global parameter to you're regex of "g" next to you're "i" at the end of your regex so it looked something like:

`/^(?:[a-z]*?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/gi`

in this case you will get multiple matches across a string in which you will need to loop through.

reference at actual fix: http://jsfiddle.net/ps1rf1uw

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it with adding the g to it but it gives me the same result.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you i wrote a quick jsfiddle that console logs out a url from a string https://jsfiddle.net/ps1rf1uw/

Comment: If you would like me to explain any of it please let me know @Dennis